# Map with bubbles with radius on basis of counting

Tags: python, scatter-plot, folium

I have this easy script for creating bubbles on map, but I would like bubbles with radius on basis of intensity.
I put an image with lat, lon and count. In finaly I put the map result, but there aren't bubbles. Where I am wrong?

```
import pandas as pd
# Load the dataset into a pandas dataframe.
df = pd.read_csv("autostrada_a_6.csv", delimiter=';', error_bad_lines=False)
# Report the number of sentences.
print('Number of sentences: {:,}\n'.format(df.shape[0]))
df.head()
locations = df.groupby(by=['latitudine','longitudine'])\
       .count()['created_at']\
       .sort_values(ascending=False)
locations
```

[image]

```
    # Make an empty map
    m = folium.Map(location=[20,0], tiles="OpenStreetMap", zoom_start=2)
    def get_radius(freq):
        if freq < 5:
          return 0.1
        elif freq < 15:
          return 0.5
        elif freq < 257:
          return 1.0
  for i,x in locations.iteritems():
   folium.CircleMarker(
      location=[i[0], i[1]],
      radius=get_radius(x),
      color='crimson',
      fill=True,
      fill_color='crimson'
   ).add_to(m)
```

[image]
[dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LpgF4XSIGZbvS_kvI6hpWghKoD6tjJVr/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: so the red points should appear as bubble?

Comment: can you share the csv so that I can try it on my machine

Comment: How can I share csv file?

Comment: upload on drive and share link

Comment: now, there is the link for dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the display seems to be that the default value for the bubble radius is 10, so the size of the bubble is indistinguishable because it is specified below that value. So, change the return value to determine the radius from a certain value. And to give markers at individual positions, we need to get the data in rows, so we are changing to `locations.iterrows()`.

```
import folium

m = folium.Map(location=[df['latitudine'].mean(), df['longitudine'].mean()], tiles="OpenStreetMap", zoom_start=8)

def get_radius(freq):
    if freq < 5:
        return 5
    elif freq < 15:
        return 15
    elif freq < 257:
          return 45
        
for i,row in locations.iterrows():
    #print(i,row)
    folium.CircleMarker(
      location=[row[0], row[1]],
      radius=get_radius(row[2]),
      color='crimson',
      fill=True,
      fill_color='crimson'
    ).add_to(m)

m
```

[image]

Comment: With 'locations.iterrows()' i have an error:'AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'iterrows''...But I could resolve with 'locations.iteritems()'. But why I have this error? And another question: but it is possible to get different colors (in this case 2 colors) for each bubbles on basis of different datatime (in this case are 2 datatime)?

Comment: From the error message, we assume that your data is pd.Series, so please convert it to a data frame as follows. `locations = locations.to_frame('value')`

Comment: You can also change the color in the same way you obtained the radius.

Comment: I tried but without success because inside 'locations' I don't have datatime. Maybe I am wrong in some part.

Comment: I am not sure what the issue is since I am not familiar with the latest data.